# (Cannot assign to property: '_products' is a 'let' constant)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Model Class

```
struct Products: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var title:String
        var price:String
        var image:String
    }
```

I am trying to change the new value of my product price by button click it showing (Cannot assign to property: '_products' is a 'let' constant)

(Cannot assign to property: '_products' is a 'let' constant)

I am trying to change the new value of my product price by button click it showing (Cannot assign to property: '_products' is a 'let' constant)

Comment: Use `var` rather than `let`. If in a `View`, the variable should be marked with `@State`. Without code or an example, we can't help anymore than that.

Comment: You haven't added the relevant code. The error mentions `_products`

Comment: @George Button(action: {
                                                        _products.price = "20"
                                                        self.homeViewModel.objectWillChange.send()
                                                        print(_products.price)
                                                        
                                                    },

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new syntax where you can have a `Binding` in a `ForEach`, giving each element as a `Binding`. Link [here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/#xcode-s-new-element-binding-syntax) to useful article about it.

This means code such as this (where `item` is a constant):

```
ForEach(items) { item in
    /* ... */
    /* item */
}
```

Can now be transformed to this (where `$item` is a `Binding`, and `item` can now be set):

```
ForEach($items) { $item in
    /* ... */
    /* item and $item */
}
```

Basically now, change your `ForEach` to this:

```
ForEach ($Topproducts) { $product in
```

And for every usage which was previously `_products`, replace it with `product`. You can now mutate the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Products: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
     var title:String
     var price:String
     var image:String
    
    init(title: String, price: String, image: String){
        self.title = title
        self.price = price
        self.image = image
        
    }
    
}
```